# rails 3, using Devise, how add :lockable after the fact?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise successfully, but decided to add the :lockable module. Our table is called Users.

I cannot find docs on how to add a new devise module (or remove one) after doing an initial setup.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to do the following in a migration

```
change_table(:users) do |t|
  t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
end
```

The fields it adds are:

```
t.integer  "failed_attempts",                     :default => 0
t.string   "unlock_token"
t.datetime "locked_at"
```

Comment: it throws an error undefined method `user_unlock_url' when tried to geenrate the mailer. I suspect I ALSO need to run some sort of generator to add more methods to my code?

Comment: have to restart the server. doh!

Comment: how to specify number of failed attempts

Comment: @hrishikeshp : it's in the devise initialiazer

Comment: Don't forget to add an index for the unlock_token  `add_index :users, :unlock_token, :unique => true`

Answer (score 1):

Devise adds a call to `devise` in your model `app/models/user.rb` in your case. You can just add `:lockable` as a parameter to that.

Comment: thanks but i'm 99% sure i also have to add a migration, and wonder if they have a helper for it or if we should add it manually, and if so, what should i add

Comment: This method works if you do it BEFORE you run the migration. If not, you have to add the migration by hand after the fact.