# NameError in Devise::SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, devise

I'm trying to use `:lockable`, and so when I add it to `class User < ActiveRecord::Base` and try to sign in or log in . I get redirect to and error page. Here's what I get

```
NameError in Devise::SessionsController#create
undefined local variable or method `locked_at' for #<User:0x000001025a56d8>

Rails.root: /Users/user/Ruby

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"dsfgsgfddsfgt5467657654n74=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"email@email.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

Any ideas? When I remove `:lockable` it all works fine

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails 3, using Devise, how add :lockable after the fact?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412801/rails-3-using-devise-how-add-lockable-after-the-fact)

Comment: Already tried that post @IsmaelAbreu

Comment: But that should be the solution for your error. Maybe you forgot to run the migration or restart the server. I can't of anything else that could result in this error

Comment: Just tried migration and restart it. Still the same error @IsmaelAbreu

Comment: OK, then add more info about your user module, and the schema

Comment: My db structure http://pastebin.com/T26BjqNK @IsmaelAbreu

Answer (score 1):

Devise requires  `datetime :locked_at` field. You must missed it.

UPDATE:

Include this migration as it looks like you dont have appropriate field in your `user` table.

do this

1. `rails g migration add_devise_required_missing_fields`
2. Open the generated migration file and paste this

   ```
   change_table(:users) do |t|
     ## Confirmable
     # t.string   :confirmation_token
     # t.datetime :confirmed_at
     # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
     # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

    ## Lockable
     t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
     t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
     t.datetime :locked_at
   end 
   add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
   ```
3. lastly , run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Open console and give me `User.new.attributes` output.

Comment: Yes, User model doesnt have `locked_at` field. You might have pending migration or you might change devise generated file after migration so that change doesnt took place. You can crosscheck it by checking `user` table in your database.

Comment: I've ran `db:migrate` and restarted the server

Comment: How long does pending mean?

Comment: I still don't see it when checking for `user`... Do I edit the `_devise_create_users.rb`?

Comment: `pending migration` is the technical term. Anyway,  You should create a new migration and add all appropriate fields as per devise module.

Comment: I'm fairly new. So how would I do that?

Comment: post this code of this file  `_devise_create_users.rb`

Comment: try now, you should atleast know how to debug such problem. Ok. try now i updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is two possible mistakes,

1. You may missed to enable the fields which need devise lockable feature

   ## Lockable

   # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts

   # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both

   # t.datetime :locked_at

You have to enable and migrate, in other word, these three inputs needed in User(if you applied devise to User model) table.

2. You may used rake db:setup command to create, migrate and seed Database. This is correct but you have to check, whether you have those three fields in db/schema.rb file because db:setup command will check schema file and run the migration. May be other co-developer who working with the same project add  that field and forget to upload schema.rb changes to git/bitbucket.